org.apache.commons is seen but FTPClient cannot be resolved to a type
I have a maven project in eclipse.
I added the apache.commons.net jar file and made all needed references and dependencies.
The intelisense  sees no issue, no red lines.
Yet when code is run from IDE it fails FTPClient cannot be resolved to a type.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: FTPClient cannot be resolved to a type FTPClient cannot be resolved to a type FTP cannot be resolved to a variable
   import org.apache.commons.net.*;
   import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;
   import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

  private void connect(){
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            USERNAME= txtUserName.getText();
            SERVERADDRESS = txtAddress.getText();
            PASS = txtPassword.toString();
              
             // Connect to the FTP server
            ftpClient.connect(SERVERADDRESS, PORT_NUM);
            ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASS);
    
            // Set file transfer type to binary
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

I have tried reopening the project.  removing it from the workspace and readding.  It compiles with errors and fails when this code is run.
I added the commons.net.jar to the Build Path and imported it to the pom.xml
I expect the reference to be seen.
I've tried several things I read here on solving the org.apache.com not being opened.
I have closed and reopened and even tried writing a new Project and got the same issue.
I added this to the Build Path and imported it to the pom.xml
The file is in a local folder, lib. The version of the jar is commons-net-3.11.1.jar
I'm new to Java and not sure how to compile a Jframe project from the command line.
What is and Where would the "Build File" be stored and I'll provide it.
POM.XML
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyTest1</groupId>
  <artifactId>T1B-A</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>T1B-A</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons.net</groupId>
     <artifactId>ftp</artifactId>
     <version>3.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

reproducible example in a java project
package myPackage;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Form1 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Form1 frame = new Form1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Form1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            MakeConnection();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
    
    public static void MakeConnection() {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
          try {
              // Connect to the FTP server
              String FTP_SERVER, FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD ;
              
              int FTP_PORT = 21;
              
              FTP_SERVER= "the address your using";
              FTP_USER = "your login name";
              FTP_PASSWORD="your password";
              
              ftpClient.connect(FTP_SERVER, FTP_PORT);
              ftpClient.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD);

              // Set file transfer type to binary
              ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              try {
                  // Disconnect from the FTP server
                  if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                      ftpClient.logout();
                      ftpClient.disconnect();
                  }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
        
    }
}


"It compiles with errors and fails when this code is run." - Yes, this is expected. The Eclipse compiler compiles the parts without compile errors and generate code that throws an Unresolved compilation problems error for the parts containing compile errors.

The dependency declaration looks wrong. The correct dependency for Apache Commons Net 3.11.1 is
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.1</version>
</dependency>

